# how to get fedex shipment xml api request and response?

Tags: php, xml, api, fedex

I want fedex shipment label api for my website. Can anyone tell me how to get fedex print shipment label XML-API for php?
How to request to the fedex and extract response.

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to the FedEx API by logging into your FedEx account and clicking on the "Developer Resource Center" link in the footer. The direct link is http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/web-services/index.html. You can download the documentation and sample code from there.

The FedEx documentation can be quite extensive & complicated. I'm working with Shippo (https://goshippo.com). We provide an easy-to-use FedEx REST API and a PHP client library. Let me know if I can help with further questions!